# How do I update AppDynamics .net agent via Powershell?

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, appdynamics

not new to coding but I have been working in python before and shaking the rust off my Powershell and working with xml. We are trying to automate the deployment of AppDynamics's .net agent and we have the deployment piece down as well as upgrade. Now I am trying to include specific applications and tiers running on IIS. So again shaking off rust here but I am trying the find a simple script to update the config.xml to add the application and update the tier from IIS. It's not a complex xml file but any help or direction would be helpful

Just trying to find the right syntax to update the nodes properly and arguments

```
#Current work
$config = "mylocation\config.xml"
$configuration = $config
[xml]$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.load($configuration)
#what will make this work !!! I have tried a few things but it's been a 
while and I am having to read up on xml again :|
$xml.Save($configuration)
```

```html
#what I need updated
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appdynamics-agent xmlns:xsd="http://stuff.com" xmlns:xsi="http://stuff.com">
  <controller host="test.saas.appdynamics.com" port="123" ssl="true" enable_tls12="true">
  <applications> #need to create this
    <application default="true" name="app1" /> #need to add the default='true' if there is more than one app
    <application name="App2"/> #this 
  </applications> #this
    <account name="testacct" password="123456" />
  </controller>
  <machine-agent />
  <app-agents>
    <IIS>
      <applications> #there by default with the default settings 
        <application controller-application="app1" path="/app1path" site="WebSite1"> # need to add this
          <tier name="app1-1" /> #and this
        </application> #this too
        <application controller-application="app2" path="/app2path" site="WebSite2"> #some more
          <tier name="app2-2" /> #you guessed it
        </application> #this as well
      </applications> #ends with this
    </IIS>
  </app-agents>
</appdynamics-agent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you are not saying that you are having errors or showing the. Yet, based on your experience to date, I am sure you already know that PowerShell provides cmdlets for working with XML.

See them using ---

```
Get-Command -Name '*xml*' | ft -a
```

or get other XML modules from the MS PowerShellGallery.com using ---

```
Find-Module -Name '*xml*' | ft -a
```

--- and install the one(s) that fit your needed goals.

And of course there are lot's of examples and videos on the topic. Searching for 'PowerShell working with XML', gives you plenty of hits.

[PowerShell Data Basics: XML](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml/)

For the most part, what you will find is very similar to what you already have posted. Yet, you say you want add nodes / elements, but that is not in your post, so, something like the below should help.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\file.xml)
$elem = $xml.Configuration.ConfigSections.AppendChild($xml.CreateNode([System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element,'section',$null))
$elem.SetAttribute('name','something')
$xml.Save('C:\file.xml')
```

Or even just using the [WebAdministration module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/) on the IIS server directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the AppDynamics agent installation PowerShell Extension: https://www.appdynamics.com/community/exchange/extension/dotnet-agent-installation-with-remote-management-powershell-extension/

It should be able to handle what you are trying to do without having to generate the xml manually, check the pdf for advanced options and read about the Add-IISApplicationMonitoring cmdlet

What it can’t do is the newer stuff like “multiple business application” and “custom node name” configuration. (Which you can’t do in the install wizard either)